# Chrome extension to execute php file

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, google-chrome-extension

For the last few days, I'm trying to build Chrome extension which will inject button to https page (done :) ). Once the button is pushed, I'm gonna read some value from DOM (done :) )and push them to test.php file (that's the problem), which will send those var to em via email.

So far I created this:

manifest.json

```
{
"name" : "test",
"version": "1.0.1",
"manifest_version": 2,
"permissions":  [
                    "tabs", "activeTab", "https://www.googleapis.com/*"
                ],
"browser_action":   {
                        "default_icon": "icon128.png"
                    },
"content_scripts":  [
                      {
                        "js": ["jquery-3.1.1.min.js", "content.js"]
                      }
                    ],
  "background":   {
                      "scripts": [ "jquery-3.1.1.min.js", "background.js" ]
                  }}
```

content.js

```
(function(window, $, undefined){  


$('#sendbutton').on('click', function(event) { 


    var campaignInfo = {
        'name' : 'test_name',
        'surname' : 'test_surname'

    };
    var datastring = JSON.stringify(campaignInfo);

    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
    method: 'POST',
    action: 'xhttp',
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/test/test.php',

    data: datastring
}); 

    console.log(campaignInfo);


  }); })(window, jQuery);
```

background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, callback) {if (request.action == "xhttp") {    $.ajax({
    type: request.method,
    url: request.url,
    data: request.data,
    success: function(responseText){
        callback(responseText);
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        callback();
    }
});

return true; }});
```

test.php

```
<?php if (isset($_POST["data"]) && !empty($_POST["data"])) { $message = $_POST["data"];} mail('testemail@gmai.com', 'test', $message); ?>
```

So, I'm able to inject button, read DOM value and send post to test.php which send email, but I'm not able to pass my array.

Can you tell me how to pass the array?

Comment: campaignInfo array from content.js through background.js to test.php

Comment: Hi all, after another 2h, I found out what was wrong, 
To fixed above code I had to modify as follow:
in content.js
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data: {result:JSON.stringify(campaignInfo)}
in php:
<?php $message    = $_POST["result"]; mail('testemail@gmail.com', 'test', $message);?>

Comment: @rkc If you have a working solution, you should post it as a (self-)answer and accept it, so that the question is not left hanging. Alternatively, you could delete the question if you think it's of no use to anybody else, but be careful, as doing that repeatedly can trigger a question ban.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after another 2h, I found out what was wrong, To fixed above code I had to modify as follow: in content.js dataType: 'JSON', data: {result:JSON.stringify(campaignInfo)} in php: